# "error TS1005: ';' expected" openDialog(){

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get the above error: `"error TS1005: ';' expected" ......` when I run `ng serve` on angular vs 16.1 typescript 5.1.3 and node.js 18.

The .ts file onclick method to open a material UI popup dialog:

```
constructor(private dialog:MatDialog){ 
    openDialog(){
        this.dialog.open(DialogBodyComponent,{
            width:"50%"
    })
  }
```

.html template called the function:

```
<button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="openDialog()">Add Staff</button>
```

I have updated @angular/cli , typescript and node.js to latest versions hoping that on compilation the dialog pops up after the button 'add staff' is clicked. please assist.

Comment: Your method defined inside constructor, its wrong, move it to the class level.